# How to use K8S env variable in python

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm deploying my python application in K8S.

I'm passing below env vars in K8S:

```
env:
    - name: DATA_GET_API
      value: "http://myapi.com/get"
    - name: DATA_PUT_API
      value: "http://myapi.com/put"
```

How can I use these variables in my python code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.environ`:

```
import os
os.environ['YOUR_CUSTOM_VAR']
```

**Note**: before using the above code, make sure that your environmental variables are available by using `printenv`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are providing these environment variable from pod's spec.

Environment variables can be accessed using `os.environ`

```
DataGetAPI = os.environ.get('DATA_GET_API')
```

DataGetAPI will be set to `None` if `DATA_GET_API` is not provided.

You can also set default value when env is not set yet instead of `None`

```
DataPutAPI = os.getenv('DATA_PUT_API', default_value)
```